# Event.observe DOMNodeRemoved does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I'm using this :

```
Event.observe('${action.extUnenrolledListId}List', 'DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {

}
```

It works in Firefox, but in IE8 the `DOMNodeRemoved` event isn't recognized.
Any ideas about an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

No. IE up to and including version 8 does not support any of the DOM mutation events. There's no equivalent.

**UPDATE**

From @4esn0k's comment, it seems that it is possible to [simulate `DOMNodeInserted` in IE using behaviors](http://blogs.developpeur.org/fremycompany/archive/2008/01/13/domnodeinserted-ajouter-son-support-sous-ie-internet-explorer-5.aspx) (untested).

Comment: there is HTC support in IE8, so there is a way to implement DOMNodeInserted at least

Comment: http://blogs.developpeur.org/fremycompany/archive/2008/01/13/domnodeinserted-ajouter-son-support-sous-ie-internet-explorer-5.aspx

Comment: @4esn0k: Thanks. I haven't tested it, but I'll add it to me answer.